SAPCRM and Amazon Connect CTI Integration
How can we integrate or use Amazon Connect CTI with SAP CRM  embedded UI.
I want to use Amazon connect we were able to integrate by using Amazon Soft phone URL, but now I want to do through SAP CRM in built UI  for accept/reject calls, call forwarding etc.
